# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/preloading/Preloader : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 while compile kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am beginner in **Kotlin**. I am getting the following exception while doing following:

```
kotlinc sample.kt -include-runtime -d sample.jar
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/jetbrains/kotlin/preloading/Preloader : Unsupported major.minor
>   version 52.0
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

Code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
      var a : Int
      a = getLength("Hello")
      println("length of word is $a")
  }

  fun getLength(word : Any) : Int? {
      if (word !is String) return null
      return word.length
  }
```

And kotlin version is `Kotlin version 1.2.21-release-88 (JRE 1.7.0_79-b15)`

Comment: What is your JDK version? Please add output of `java -version` command.

Comment: Got it.  Now I have updated the jdk.

java -version
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)

Works fine. Thanks @asm0dey

Comment: Added answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK version which was used to build `sample.jar` is built with java version newr than one which you're using to compile kotlin file.
You have 2 ways:

1. Rebuild sample jar with your current version of JDK
2. Update JDK on your computer and try compiling again

Comment: Thanks @asm0dey . I have updated my JDK.  Please let me know how to rebuild sample jar with your current version of JDK. Is there any comment?

Comment: If code is available to you — you can rebuild it, obviously :)

Answer (score 0):

Install an updated JDK, Go to File > Project Structure. Select the newer JDK version.
Then you'll be ready to go.